# In a Unity canvas a button and an image hide each other even though they don't overlap

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my Unity project I have a canvas with a button and an image inside. I have noticed that even though they don't overlap (they are quite distance) they cover each other. So when the button is below the image in the Hierarchy panel the image is not shown. Meanwhile when the image is below the button I cannot view the image attached to button. Nevertheless I can see the button text...

[image: if the button is above the image it can't be viewe properly]

[image: if the button is below it can be viewd properly but the image can't be seen at all]

Comment: That's an interesting issue - could you include screenshots of the problem behaviour, and maybe the components/scene hierarchy of the relevant UI elements? That could help us figure out what's going on.

Comment: If, in the hierarchy, the image YouWin is above the button then YouWin can be see properly but we can only see the text of the button. On the opposite if the button is below the image the button is displayed properly, but the image YouWin is not displayed at all